# 新しい 机 を 買って もらいました。"They bought me a new desk" or "I bought and received a new desk"?

Tags: translation, meaning, verbs, word-order

Ok, so I was studying some Japanese phrases when this showed up: 新しい 机 を 買って もらいました。

The translation provided in the source material is: "They bought me a new desk"

What I don't understand, however, is the verb placement. From what I can perceive, the te-form in the 買う is used to connect it with the verb もらう. How do I know which is the subject for each verb? I mean, how do I distinguish that 買って's subject is "they" and that もらう's subject is "me"?

How do I know if this phrase means "They bought me a new desk" instead of "I bought and received a new desk"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you use もらう, it always means to receive from someone else. It is unusual to use もらう for anything you receive from yourself:

> 私は自分からこのケーキをもらった。 "I got this cake from me." <-- this sounds crazy

Moreover, it's odd to use もらう for getting or receiving things from stuff that isn't willingly or consciously giving it to you:

> ジョンさんは、棚から千円もらった。 "John received one thousand yen from the shelf." <-- crazy, shelves can't give people stuff

Basically, もらう is the reciprocal form of くれる or あげる, so that the participants and viewpoint are switched. View もらう as though it's a rewording of あげる or くれる:

> 彼が　武田さんに　新しいコートを　買ってあげました "He bought Mr. Takeda a new coat."
>
> 武田さんが　彼に　新しいコートを　買ってもらいました "He bought Mr. Takeda a new coat."

Comment: I see, so it is basically just a specification from the verb もらう itself. Thank you for the answer, that pretty much clarifies it.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: No one would say that last sentence.

Comment: @l'électeur. You're right, that sentence wouldn't come up very often.

Comment: Usually it is interpreted as an auxiliary verb, literally `I received (the favour of) getting bought a desk.`. But I wonder, could it *possibly* (=twisting words) be taken as a full verb in the sense of「新しい机を買って(、店員さんからその机を)もらった。」?

Comment: @blutorange. I don't think there's much chance of it being confused by a native speaker, since when you buy something you kind of automatically receive it. However, something like ボールを選んでもらった could mean "I picked a ball and received it," but mainly because people picking things for you isn't usually seen as a favor.

Comment: @YsAdamsson ボールを選んでもらった "I picked a ball and received it", doesn't make much sense. Almost all natives will take it as "(someone) picked a ball for me". If I want to say "I picked a ball and received it" I will probably go with "ボールを選んで（から）受け取った"